# Why didn't the Allies attack Germany from the South?

Tags: world-war-two, tactics, strategy

I was thinking about how and when Italy was captured and converted into a Pro-Allies country. Once the Germans were pushed out of Italy and it was completely under Allied control, why did the Invasion of Normandy have to happen. It seems to me there were two other significant options available to the Allies in terms of their next move.

For example:

1. Invading Austria from the South

This would have put direct pressure on Germany and put the Allies closer to Berlin and for the the first time threatened Germany directly.

2. Invading France from the East

Why make a large amphibious invasion at Normandy when you can walk into Vichy France from Italy?

I have never heard or read anything about either of these options so I am curious what facts can be brought to light on them.

Comment: `Once the Germans were pushed out of Italy and it was completely under Allied control,` The issue is that it did not happen, check the wikipedia article about the Italian campaign.

Comment: Italy was liberated in spring 1945, while Normandy landing happened in summer 1944.

Comment: In general questions that focus on "Why not..." verge on counterfactuals which are out of scope.  As was pointed out in the comments, you're also arguing from a potential counterfactual (Italy under Allied control).  Consider asking, "Why did the allies choose the option they did?" rather than "Why didn't they ...". Please, consider revising your question iaw site standards rather than attacking votes cast on the question.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace "As was pointed out in the comments" where exactly?
Your comment being the basis for down-voting, particularly on a new user completely turns me off to this community, especially for something so basic.

Comment: @jacksonecac both SJuan76's and Alex's point out the flaw in your reasoning, in re the dates Northern Italy was actually in full control of the allied forces. Perhaps you might benefit from a bit more study of factual history and dates. Mark was simply informing you of the standards of this particular site, which are different, in their own way, than many of the other SEs.

Comment: The Allies didn't capture Rome, never mind northern Italy, until June 4, 1944, two days before the Normandy invasion. So your proposals weren't feasible on June 6, 1944.

Comment: Comments spot on.

Comment: @Alex +1. There may be some evidence that Churchill favoured a southern assault and was over-ruled by the Americans (that position has been dramatised). The senior British military hierarchy had served in the first world war, and were paranoid of a drive through France getting bogged down in the mud of Flanders. But perhaps after considering the fate of the Italian army at Trentino in 1916, the thought of crossing the Alps by holding the Brenner pass (1400metres), seemed even more formidable than the amphibious Overlord.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Germans managed to hold northern Italy, by defending the [Gothic Line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gothic_Line), until March 1945. After that, the German position began to crumble rapidly, until they [surrendered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_Campaign_(World_War_II)#Allied_advance_into_Northern_Italy) on 29th April, with hostilities ceasing on 2nd May. Since there was less than a week of the European war left, there was no time to organise an attack northwards before the final German surrender.